# How do I update someone else's iOS TestFlight build in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a new build to TestFlight.  I was invited to App Store Connect as an admin, and I added my Apple ID in Xcode.  There is already an existing TestFlight build a bygone developer has put up there, but I've taken over the project and need to update it.  I can build the app in the simulator just fine, but when I try to make a build for a generic iOS device I get these two errors:

```
    Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "com.blahblahlbah.blahblahblah" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
    No profiles for 'com.blahblahlbah.blahblahblah were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.blahblahlbah.blahblahblah'.
```

I don't see any way to select a different team.  Do I need to enroll in the developer program?  I'm using Macincloud to try to build the app from Ionic, so I don't have an iOS device to set up two-factor authentication with, but I can get one if that is required to get this to work.  Are there some build settings that I have to set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got the last developer to revoke their certificate.  Turns out there was some issue with my account not being able to register for the developer program.  After dealing with their support for a while I just made a new account.  Then I was finally able to create a new certificate and select it in XCode.  After that, it built just fine.